# What window is active after click toast notification - AHK

Tags: autohotkey

i'm browsing google chrome then toast notification appears on bottom right.
i click it and it disappears.
after that i can see google chrome as top window, it looks like a active window but it's not activated.
then sometimes i press ctrl+t to open new tab in google chrome but it doesnt work because its not activated.
its annoying.
i want to make like below one.

```
#If WinActive("After Click Toast")
    ^t::
        WinActivate ahk_exe chrome.exe
        WinWaitActive ahk_exe chrome.exe
        Send %A_ThisHotkey%
        return
```

after click toast, windows spy doesnt show anything.

```
MsgWinTitle(){
    WinGet, ExStyle, ExStyle, A
    MsgBox % ExStyle
    return
}
```

but with this shows 0x08200000
i dont know how can i use this though.

thanks for read.
thanks for help.

Comment: What does WinSpy show before you click on the toast? Does WinSpy say anything about the toast window? Perhaps you could use that to reactivate that window with a timer or something. The only option otherwise I can think of is loop through active windows, find one that has the same ExStyle with WinGet on each, until you find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Big advise
now i solved it with this

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow")
~LButton:: return
~LButton Up:: 
    Send {Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}
    return
```